# How to count recursive relationships in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, eloquent, relationship

I have a problem with recursive relationships in Laravel 8 (php8). I will try to simplify my case, so let's have two models - `Article` and `Comment`.

The `Article` model is pretty basic, but the `Comment` model has a polymorphic relationship, and to add some little bit of spice - `Comment` is commentable. That means, that this is very likely to happen:

```
Article[id:3]
  - Comment[id:1]
    - Comment[id:8]
    - Comment[id:9]
  - Comment[id:2]
    - Comment[id:3]
      - Comment[id:4]
        - Comment[id:7]
    - Comment[id:5]
  - Comment[id:6]
```

But it can happen on a larger scale as well - discussions might be huge, which might lead to hundreds of comments in several layers... And now I would need a method, that will count all the comments (incl. the nested ones) with as few queries as possible.

Because a lot of comment-related methods repeat on different models (not just the articles), I created a trait `Comments`, so:

```
/**
 * @property Comment[]|EloquentCollection $comments
 * @property Comment[]|EloquentCollection $allComments
 */
trait Comments
{ 
  public function comments(): MorphMany
  {
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
  }

  public function allComments(): MorphMany
  {
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->with('allComments');
  }

  /* This will return 3 */
  protected function getCommentsCountAttribute($when = 'now'): int
  {
    if (is_string($when)) $when = Date::parse($when);
    elseif (!$when instaceof Carbon) $when = Date::now();

    return $this->comments()->whereDate('created_at','<=',$when)->count();
  }

  protected function getCommentsTotalCountAttribute($when = 'now'): int
  {
    // What to do here without burning the database or the PHP server?
    return 9;
  }
}


class Article extends Model
{
  use Traits\Comments;
}

class Comment extends Model
{
  use Traits\Comments;
}
```

I have not found a solution on how to make it on the database layer - not sure if recursive MySQL queries are possible (I'm not aware of that). But also, eager-loading an `Article` with thousands of `Comments` might be a way to hell - especially if the database will grow to an enormous scale.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8, you can try a Recursive CTE query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples

Comment: @Pipe I'm gonna check that out, but I'm a bit reserved from using DB/version-specific solutions. When Laravel uses Eloquent or DB facade, then if the database config changed, this might not work anymore. But thank you anyway